# fread from c++ binary file returning wrong value

Tags: c++, file-io, binaryfiles, fread, stdio

I am trying to read and write some boolean grids to a file using `stdio.h`. The user inputs a number `nx` (from 1 to 10, generally) and the program generates a list of `nx` by `ceil(nx / 2)` boolean grids (`ceil(nx / 2)` is `ny`). The grids themselves are stored in `__int64`s, so this grid (`f` is false and `T` is true):

```
ffTT
fTfT
```

would be 172 (10101100).

The end list of grids is outputted to a binary file.

My code:

```
std::vector<__int64> grids;

...

FILE *cFile;
if (fopen_s(&cFile, ("grid_" + std::to_string(nx) + "_c.bin").c_str(), "wb") != 0) return;

for (int i = 0; i < grids.size(); i++) {
    fwrite(&grids[i], (int) ceil((nx * ny) / 8), 1, cFile);
}

fclose(cFile);
```

This part works fine.

---

However, when I try to read from a file, all of the grids are -858993460, regardless of size, although it gets the number of grids correct. My code for reading:

```
FILE *cFile;
if (fopen_s(&cFile, ("grid_" + std::to_string(nx) + "_c.bin").c_str(), "rb") != 0) return;

fseek(cFile, 0, SEEK_END);
long size = ftell(cFile);

int grids = size / ((nx * ny) / 8);

for (int n = 0; n < shapes; n++) {
    __int64 data;
    fread(&data, (int) ceil((nx * ny) / 8), 1, cFile);
    printf("%i\n", data);
}

fclose(cFile);
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

If you need any more information to answer, leave a comment and I'll give it to you.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the purpose of using `ceil` here?

Comment: @RSahu It makes the output an integer number of bytes. Not using `ceil` would round down, so 603 would end up as 91.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

The problem is that you are moving the `FILE*` to the end of the file using:

```
fseek(cFile, 0, SEEK_END);
```

And then, you are trying to read the data without going back to the start of the file.

You are not checking the returned value of:

```
fread(&data, (int) ceil((nx * ny) / 8), 1, cFile);
```

to check whether the read was successful or not.

**Fix**

Add the line

```
fseek(cFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

to rewind the file.

Always check the return value of reading operations.

```
if ( fread(&data, (int) ceil((nx * ny) / 8), 1, cFile) == 1 )
{
   // Successful read.
   // Use the data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `fwrite` and `fread` in strange ways. Please do

```
 fwrite(&gris[i], sizeof(__int64), 1, cFile);
```

for dump and

```
 fread(&data, sizeof(__int64), 1, cFile);
```

for recovering.

Comment: `sizeof(__int64)` would always return 8. I am shooting for the smallest filesize possible, therefore I use `(int) ceil((nx * ny) / 8)`, the smallest possible size.

Comment: Yes, but for storing a single item you must specify at least 1 byte. The element size is independent of array size.

Comment: Each array is `nx` by `ny`

Comment: yes but you pass &grids[i] (that's a __int64*) when writting and fwrite takes account of the bytes of the element: the second parameter cannot be used for write a single bit, the minimum is 1 byte. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/
The same happens for fread.